# Using GAPI to get Metrics without Dimensions

Tags: php, api, google-analytics

I am attempting to use the gapi php class to get basic stats from analytics. I only need data for the past 30 days with no specific dimensions. This would be the same as looking at analytics with no segmentation. I started with this:

```
$ga->requestReportData($acc['profileId'],array('visitorType'),array('pageviews', 'uniquePageviews', 'exitRate', 'avgTimeOnPage', 'entranceBounceRate'));
```

Obviously this is using the dimension of "visitorType" and as such my results are split. Rather than adding the results, I'd rather just have a clean object as the output. What needs to be used as the Dimensions parameter to just get raw data from the whole site?

Comment: There seems to be a very old bug report pertaining to that issue: https://code.google.com/p/gapi-google-analytics-php-interface/issues/detail?id=13&q=dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

Looking over the `gapi.class.php` file, it shows that dimensions are a required parameter:

```
@param String $report_id
@param Array $dimensions Google Analytics dimensions e.g. array('browser')
@param Array $metrics Google Analytics metrics e.g. array('pageviews')
@param Array $sort_metric OPTIONAL: Dimension or dimensions to sort by e.g.('-visits')
@param String $filter OPTIONAL: Filter logic for filtering results
more optional params....
```

If you want to send in only metrics, then you will have to edit the `gapi.class.php`

**This is COMPLETELY untested because I don't use GAPI but here is what I would try first:**

Change this `else` to an `else if` around line 126 in the `requestReportData` method:

```
....
  $parameters['dimensions'] = substr($dimensions_string,1);
}
else 
{
  $parameters['dimensions'] = 'ga:'.$dimensions;
}
....
```

Change to this:

```
else if(is_string($dimensions) && strlen(trim($dimensions)) > 0)
{
  $parameters['dimensions'] = 'ga:'.$dimensions;
}
```

We are trying to prevent the dimensions from being added to the google api call.

And, finally, once the edits are in, call `requestReportData` as such:

```
$ga->requestReportData($acc['profileId'],'',array('pageviews', 'uniquePageviews', 'exitRate', 'avgTimeOnPage', 'entranceBounceRate'));
```